# Which is better for website performance. PHP MySQL Query or plain HTML?

Tags: php, html, performance, pagespeed

In terms of speed, performance, or plainly which is better for a website?

Lets say an html `select` tag with a lot of `option` tags inside, like for example `100`

Would it be better to simply encode them right away with plain html like so . .

```
<select>
  <option value="1">First Something</option>
  <option value="2">Another Something</option>
  .
  .
  .
  <option value="100">Last Something</option>
</select>
```

or would it be better to query the values from a db and use php to setup the tags?

And how about for just `10` `option` tags inside a `select` tag? PHP + MySQL or just plain HTML?

Comment: The choice is not a question of performance. If the list is static, there's no reason to store it in a database. On the other hand if the list contains data that is user-specific or something that changes over time, it should be stored in a db.

Comment: @Juhana I'm just concerned on pagespeed. Is it good to have `select` tags with 100 `option tags` or more hard coded in pure html? I have about 3 of them the other one has about 160 `option tags` inside. Doesn't that increase page size and slows down pagespeed? querying them from a db reduces page size but again there is the processing and querying time. I'm just unsure of which would be faster.

Comment: I don't really understand how you expect the database to speed up the page. After you've populated the list from the database, it's the same size as if you had a static list, is it not? The page size doesn't change at all. In any case 160 tags is practically nothing.

Comment: `same size as if you had a static list . . .The page size doesn't change at all` <- I actually don't know if the page size decreases or increases. I thought that when people talk about page size its the actual file size of the current page. Learned something new today. Thanks for the info!

Comment: The confusion might come from looking just the PHP file's size. What happens is that the server first processes the PHP file and only then sends the generated HTML file to the user, not the PHP code. The transferred file is what you see if you right click and select "view source" in the browser. So you see that regardless of how the server generates the page it sends the same amount of data to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doubt PHP/MySQL would be slower.

Because if it's in HTML it would just print them, if it's PHP it will do the querying then print the same, so Step 1 takes shorter than Step 2 + Step 1.

PHP would be shorter in your point of view but for the visitor it's the same populated page.

Comment: I was actually thinking that. I just needed some reassurance. thanks!

Comment: of course it slower but the benefits far out way the few nanoseconds you save - of course caching bridges the divide between dynamic and static.

Answer (score 2):

Writing select html tags directly in HTML is much faster than generating them from PHP. To make web page more faster and to display dynamic content you can load select elements after the page load using ajax when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think page size is important with respect to performance and scalability. Performance only matters,only if it's bottleneck or page is too slow. But I don't think, 1 query will be bottleneck. So, in my views, in this requirement, most important is human performance. So, readability, easy to change is most important. For me, i use pure html or php array suits me. If list is too long or multiple dimension like city, state, etc then I use database. PHP array has benefits that changing one line changes all loop. Like change in html design changes all loop. Example,

```
$i=0;
foreach($list as $element){
    ++$i;
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $element; ?></option>
<?php
}
```

Now, if you need to change it, just change in 1 line changes all options. Also it helps in validation,like

```
<?php
$allowed_values = array("value1","value2"....);
if(in_array($_POST['value'],$allowed_values)){
    //process form
}else{
    //error user has posted wrong values
}
```